Approaches to Atiayh Singer index theorem

Soon i will have to choose a scientific  adviser.
Mathematicians in my university almost explicitly work on theory of ( partial ) differential equations, which i do not really like.
But there is one professor, who is interested in Index theory.
I already read some resources and understood, that in all proofs of Atiayh-Singer Theorem there are used many branches of mathematics, mainly Functional Analysis and Algebraic Topology.
I found these topics pretty interesting by themselves and especially was amused by their fusion.
Now my goal is to study something related to Index Theory this summer, to get even tiny understanding of it.

My question is next: what approach to Atiyah-Singer theorem among

Topological K-theory
K-theory of C*-algebras
Heat equation
( Probably there are exist another approaches ? )

is easier and gives more insight on theory ?.

If they are similarly hard, then  maybe you can provide any sort of arguements to study exactly that one proof ?.
Also, it will be very helpful, if you could list some resources ( preferably, books with explanations ).

